# can JS automatically assign keys like PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, object, assign

in PHP, keys can automatically be assigned without requiring a name or variable:

```php
$myObject = ['someCrap' =>[]];
for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++) {
  $myObject['someCrap'][] = 90 * $i;
};
var_dump($myObject);
```

can this be done in Javascript?  i've tried the following code:

```js
let myObject = {'someCrap':{}}
for(let i=0;i<=10;i++) {
  myObject['someCrap'][] = 90 * i
}
console.log({myObject})
```

which yields `Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got ']'`. is there a way to make this happen ***without using counters***, or is that the only way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an array, not an object. The JS equivalent of assigning to `[]` is the `.push()` method.

```js
let myObject = {
  'someCrap': []
}
for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  myObject['someCrap'].push(90 * i)
}
console.log(myObject)
```

Comment: well alrighty then!  :)  thank you.  does that work if what i want to push is an object itself? ------> eg. push({name: 'Jorge'})

Comment: coming from PHP, JS feels downright tetchy sometimes... like that hot chick who always seems slightly irritated but endures your shenanigans anyway until you put a fork in the spoon slot, then she loses her mind.